# What architecture to use in OSX?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, mpi

I finished installing boost mpi, with openmpi as the underlying implementation, and trying to compile a simple program to test.

I compile my boost mpi library as follow:

```
./bjam toolset=darwin architecture=x86 address-model=32 install
```

I compiled my mpi program with following:

```
mpic++ -I/opt/boost_1_46_1/include mpi_play.cpp -L/opt/boost_1_46_1/lib -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization
```

But it says

```
ld: warning: in /opt/boost_1_46_1/lib/libboost_mpi.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

I knew that the bjam command that I used was for building the library in i386. This is what I need to do for using boost thread library in XCode. So, now I am not sure what is the best approach to make all these boost libraries and mpi libraries work in mac.

Comment: The code should work fine (at least it does for me) are you using 10.7 or 10.6? The only time I get the issue is when I force 64 bit on OS 10.6 but I haven't tried 10.7 yet so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want i386 builds, pass `-arch i386` to mpic++, which should pass it on to the underlying compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `address-model=64` to the bjam command line to create an x86_64 MPI library you can link against your code. Or compile your code as x86 (`-arch i386`) to use the already-x86 MPI library you previously compiled.